# Why can’t Windows 98 be installed on latest computers?

Tags: windows

Why can’t [Windows 98](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_98)  be installed on latest computers?

Comment: TL;dr: has ancient drivers that just doesn't know how to figure out how SATA works.

Comment: I think the better question is, why are you trying to install Windows 98?

Comment: The last time I tried to install W98 on anything I found it was impossible to install with 2gb or more of memory.  (You could get it to run by modifying a config file but you had to install it with less memory available to be able to do that.)

Comment: In addition to SATA not being supported, Win98 can have troubles with "too much" RAM.  (The definition of "too much" may vary between computers: 1.5GB or 2GB...  there are workarounds that may help a bit, but there may still be other trouble).  Also, Win98 may have some 16-bit code, which might not work on 64-bit CPUs if the system starts with 32-bit code and goes into an x64 enhanced mode.  (Presumably the boot files may be like 16-bit DOS, but FreeDOS w/ XFDisk has been known to fail on x64.)  Driver support may be sparse.  Firefox 2.0 and IE6 oughtta work, but lots of software won't.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 98 is 17 years old. It was supported until 2006 giving it an 8 year lifespan; quite generous by any OS standards.

The core issue — literally — is that Microsoft’s decision to EOL (end of life) the OS effectively means they are not updating the core framework and not writing core drivers that can support modern hardware such as SATA controllers or even things like USB 3.0 or even USB 2.0.

As a result, no developers are incentivized to even develop for Windows 98 because why waste the effort? Aging core framework and driver support stack? No security updates? Shrinking user base? Why would anyone spend any time with Windows 98 in 2015.

So without core driver support—which is the main thing that is “dropped” when a manufacturer drops an OS version—then Windows 98 is dead in the water as far as modern hardware is concerned.